# Error while trying to use a constructor in the main program yet constructor is defined

Tags: java, class, object, methods, constructor

Editted question: in my main program I try to use one of the constructors and I get a message that says the constructor is undefined though I did define it. This error applies also for other methods I tried to use in the main program as if the main does not connect well with the other classes. Does anyone recognize any missing elements? Thanks a lot.

This is the constructor I wrote:

```
public Product(int prodCode, String prodName, float price) {
    setProdCode(prodCode);
    setProdName(prodName);
    setPrice(price);
 }
```

This is my main program:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Main {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    int chooseCategory;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    Product[] product = new Product[5];
    product[0] = new Product(100, "gf"  , 5.90f );
    product[1] = new Product(200, "IPhone" , 500.0f);
    product[2] = new Product(300, "Cola"   , 6.0f  );
    product[3] = new Product(400, "Orbit"  , 2.60f );
    product[4] = new Product(500, "TShirt" , 25.0f );

  }

}
```

Comment: Share the `main` method, please.

Comment: might be you are calling directly method without using instance

Comment: Please add your main method. Then we would be able help

Comment: Provide a main method. Without it we can just guess where's the problem

Comment: Aight. I guess the error is deeper than that, I will provide my main method soon. Thank you for responding.

Answer (score 2):

You should either define the method as 'static', or create an instance of Store first.

```
Store myStore = new Store();
myStore.addProductToStore(product);
```

Comment: I doubt he would get the error message that he gets if this was the issue.